# Value not show in Grid and Text box using JSON response mvc c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json

I want to show Specific Product Data through ID, Through Master Grid I click the Link and Pass the data on another page. I use this method but data do not show in From and Grid. Any Expert can you tell me where I am wrong. I have shown the JSON response. I also debug the code data show but not display in textbox and Grid.

C#

```
public ActionResult GetProduct_Detail(int id)
{
    var resultProdD = _IProducts.GetProductByID(id);
    JsonSerializerSettings jss = new JsonSerializerSettings { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore };
    var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resultProdD, Formatting.Indented, jss);
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Json Response**

```
{
   "listProducts":{
      "Customers":[

      ],
      "P_Color":{
         "Products":[

         ],
         "C_ID":3,
         "C_Name_OR_Code":"Green     "
      },
      "P_Size":{
         "Products":[

         ],
         "S_ID":2,
         "S_Size":"MediumNa            "
      },
      "ProductDetail":{
         "ProductID":6,
         "PDescription":"s",
         "Model":"s         ",
         "Condition":"s         ",
         "OS":"s",
         "DualSim":"s   ",
         "TouchScreen":"ss  ",
         "ScreenSize":"s         ",
         "ProcessorType":"s         ",
         "Camera":"s     ",
         "RAM":"s    ",
         "InternalMemory":"s         ",
         "Wifi":"s  ",
         "BatteryLife":"s         ",
         "Discount":54.0,
         "Other":"s",
         "ImageUrl":"~/upload/20095729TERI NAZAR Song LYRICS.jpg"
      },
      "ProductType":{
         "Products":[

         ],
         "PType_ID":1,
         "P_Name":"mobile                                            ",
         "P_Description":"mobile",
         "Active":false
      },
      "ProductID":6,
      "PName":"s                                                 ",
      "UnitWeight":0.0,
      "UnitInStock":4.0,
      "P_SizeID":2,
      "P_Color_ID":3,
      "PType_ID":1,
      "ManificturedPrice":52.0
   },
   "listProductDetails":[
      {
         "Product":{
            "Customers":[

            ],
            "P_Color":{
               "Products":[

               ],
               "C_ID":3,
               "C_Name_OR_Code":"Green     "
            },
            "P_Size":{
               "Products":[

               ],
               "S_ID":2,
               "S_Size":"MediumNa            "
            },
            "ProductType":{
               "Products":[

               ],
               "PType_ID":1,
               "P_Name":"mobile                                            ",
               "P_Description":"mobile",
               "Active":false
            },
            "ProductID":6,
            "PName":"s                                                 ",
            "UnitWeight":0.0,
            "UnitInStock":4.0,
            "P_SizeID":2,
            "P_Color_ID":3,
            "PType_ID":1,
            "ManificturedPrice":52.0
         },
         "ProductID":6,
         "PDescription":"s",
         "Model":"s         ",
         "Condition":"s         ",
         "OS":"s",
         "DualSim":"s   ",
         "TouchScreen":"ss  ",
         "ScreenSize":"s         ",
         "ProcessorType":"s         ",
         "Camera":"s     ",
         "RAM":"s    ",
         "InternalMemory":"s         ",
         "Wifi":"s  ",
         "BatteryLife":"s         ",
         "Discount":54.0,
         "Other":"s",
         "ImageUrl":"~/upload/20095729TERI NAZAR Song LYRICS.jpg"
      }
   ],
   "ProductID":0,
   "PName":null,
   "UnitWeight":0.0,
   "UnitInStock":0,
   "P_SizeID":0,
   "ProductSize":null,
   "P_Color_ID":0,
   "ProductColor":null,
   "PType_ID":0,
   "ProductType":null,
   "ManificturedPrice":0.0,
   "PDescription":null,
   "Model":null,
   "Condition":null,
   "OS":null,
   "DualSim":null,
   "TouchScreen":null,
   "ScreenSize":null,
   "ProcessorType":null,
   "Camera":null,
   "RAM":null,
   "InternalMemory":null,
   "Wifi":null,
   "BatteryLife":null,
   "Discount":0,
   "Other":null,
   "ImageUrl":null
}
```

**Function**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;
        var baseUrl = (window.location).href; // You can also use document.URL
        var id = baseUrl.substring(baseUrl.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);
        list_ProductDetail(id);
    });
    function list_ProductDetail(id)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Items/GetProduct_Detail",
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { id: id },
            success: function (result) {

                $('#PName').val(result.PName);
                $('#ManificturedPrice').val(result.ManificturedPrice);
                $('#UnitWeight').val(result.UnitWeight);

                $.each(result, function (key, item) {
                    var html = '';
                    html += '<tr>';
                    html += '<td>' + item.ProductID + '</td';
                    html += '<td>' + item.OS + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + item.PrcessorType + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + item.RAM + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + item.ScreenSize + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + item.TouchScreen + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + item.BatteryLife + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + item.Camera + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + item.Model + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + item.Condition + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + item.Discount + '</td>';
                    html += '<td><a class="menu-action rounded-btn btn menu-icon vd_bd-grey vd_grey" data-toggle="tooltip" href="#" onclick="return GetProductDetail(' + item.ProductID + ')"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a> | <a href="#" onclick="Delete(' + item.ProductID + ')"><i class="fa fa-thrash"></i></a></td>';
                });
                $('tbody').append(html);  
            },
            error: function (errormessage) {
                alert(errormessage.responseText);
            },
        });
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Hi I'm not too sure of the question here, but looking at your json it's not returning a array so hence the loop won't work. What are you trying to loop>

Comment: I try this code @RichardHousham which I have shared. My Question is a sample I want to display this JSON response using jquery. but due to some problems My JSON response not display value.

Comment: Try and use console.log(result) in chrome and the console to see what you are getting back and how to reference it in your javascript